# Crucial? mysqldump Version Mismatch

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I want to backup my mysql database.

When making the backup with mysql workbench (via: "Server" - "Data Export"), I get a notification:

> mysqldump Version Mismatch
>
> /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/mysqldump is version 5.7.9, but the MySQL Server to be dumped has version 5.7.17.
> Because the version of mysqldump is older than the server, some features may not be backed up properly.
> It is recommended you upgrade your local MySQL client programs, including mysqldump to a version equal to or newer than that of the target server.
> The path to the dump tool must then be set in Preferences -> Administrator -> Path to mysqldump Tool:

Question:
can I ignore this mismatch for these very versions? Or is it really dangerous?

Comment: This can safely be ignored for 99.999% cases.

Answer (score 1):

download the exact ("mysql-5.7.17-winx64")version of your windows operating system extract it go to --bin --find "mysqldump or mysqldump.exe" copy it and go ("Mysql Server 5.7") then find --bin again and paste it their restart your workbench and viola..problem solve..!!!!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: really poor explanation, needs more info.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. MySQL was installed from WampServer, by the other hand I have installed MysqlWorkbench. if your installation is similar, do the following:

1. Go to the Wampserver folder and go to \bin\mysql\mysql5..(version)..\bin and copy mysqldump.exe (which is newer than the version you have in your workbench);
2. Go to Program files\mysql\mysqlworkbench..(version).. and Paste overwriting the existing mysqldump.exe
3. Close Windows Explorer. Restart your workbench.

Comment: To be safe, I first renamed the destination mysqldump.exe so that I could still get it in case I screwed up.